# Создание custom элемента javafx

Tags: javafx

Приложение использует fxml, содержит два элемента `LineChart`. Также создал свой класс наследник от `LineChart`, но не могу понять, как его использовать. Создать `custom` элемент из него не получается (хотя может, что не так делаю), постоянно пишет ошибку:

> Unable to instantiate.

Возможно ли создавать из своих классов такие элементы? Если да, то как? Или может есть какой другой способ в рамках использования fxml?

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы тебе создать какой-либо компонент, ты должен сделать следующее:

1. Унаследовать свой класс от одного из компонентов ( в твоем случае от LineChart)
2. В fxml добавить импорт с этим классом
3. В описании самого элемента в fxml ты должен описать стартовые параметры - это параметры, которые ты передаешь в конструктор.

Пример

```
public class MyLineChart<X, Y> extends LineChart<X, Y> {

   String field1;
   Intger field2;

   public class MyLineChart(String field1, Integer field2, Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis) {
      super(xAsix, yAxis);
      this.field1 = field1;
      this.field2 = field2;
   }
```

fxml

```
<MyLineChart field1="SomeString" field2="100" xAsix="" yAxis=""/>
```

P.S. а вообще создай класс, не включай его в fxml, а просто в ручную добавь его на панель ( в методе `initialize` создай новый инстанс своего класса, и добавь его туда, куда тебе надо)

**UPDATE**

Тогда сделай так, если fxml не работает

```
<BorderPane id="" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="232.0" prefWidth="289.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="charts2.Controller">
    <top>
        <Pane id="pnHeader" prefHeight="67.0" prefWidth="790.0">
            <children>
                <Label id="lblTitle" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="15.0" text="MyJavaFX">
                    <textFill>
                        <Color blue="0.250" green="0.250" red="0.250" fx:id="x1" />
                    </textFill>
                </Label>
            </children>
        </Pane>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

А в классе Controller.java напиши следующие

```
package charts2;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

    public class Controller {

        private LineMarkerChart lmc;

        @Ovveride
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
            this.lmc = new LineMarketChart("asd",100,new Axis(), new Axis()); }
    }
```

Comment: Попробовал сделать как ты посоветовал - не получилось, или я опять что то упустил [ссылка](http://www.fayloobmennik.net/5404080)

Comment: Если использовать второй метод (создать класс и подключить его в методе `initialize`), то все работает

Comment: см изменненый ответ